# ConnectionString in app.config API with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, xaml

I am currently on a solution in ASP.net containing two project. One MVC project and the other is a class library serving as an API.

[image]

Currently I have a connection string like this in the web config of my project MVC.

[image]

I read it with the following code in my API:

```
public ConnectionProvider()
{
    this.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connection.Name].ConnectionString.ToString();
    factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connection.Name].ProviderName.ToString());
}
```

The problem is that I would like to move the connection string in the app.config of my API and by default but every time it starts, it will read in the web.config.

Comment: Create a resources file in the class library and fetch it from there?

Comment: of course it will, a web application will use web.config and a windows application will use app.config. A referenced project will run under the parent's settings. You can try the solution proposed by Deiter B.

Comment: Just copy the the connection string from the api and have it in the web.config. By using the resource file there is no way to update that connection string without having to recompile. Using a resource file is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using a resource file is a bad idea.

Just copy the the connection string from the api and have it in the web.config. By using the resource file there is no way to update that connection string without having to recompile.

The web application will use web.config and the connection string will be accessible from there. If the same api is to be reused in another project, say a desktop application, again just copy the connection string to the config file of the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested via comment, I would use a resource file in the class library.

While @Nkosi is not wrong that the connectionstring will be static, it's the easiest way to carry the connectionstring across w/o having an actual API or database call.

However, it's not the entire application that needs to be republished.
If the functionality in the code of the class library does not change, you can simply build the class library and overwrite the .dll of it.

Another valuable solution would be to save the connectionstring in a separate text file which all solutions will use.
Then you can replace that piece of code in all your applications while having 1 centralized point of access which can be replaced w/o building and replacing anything :).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

Thanks to Dieter B!

With a resource file:

[image]

And for read it in the API:

```
public ConnectionProvider()
{
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Bank.Project.API.resources", GetAssemblyByName("Bank.Project.API"));

    this.connectionString = rm.GetString(Connection.Name);
    this.factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(rm.GetString(Connection.Factory));
}

Assembly GetAssemblyByName(string name)
{
    var Myassembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().
           SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == name);
    return Myassembly;
}
```